# How To Rebuild Index of a specific table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, indexing, alter, rebuild

I am wondering how to rebuild an index of specific table.

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX '||OWNER||'.'||INDEX_NAME||' REBUILD;' 
FROM DBA_INDEXES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'JR_SETTING_D';
```

After running this code, I have tried to insert values in the table but it keeps telling me that

> ORA-01502: index or partition of such index is in usable state tips

I am looking for any way of simply rebuilding the table's indexes that I have  mentioned in the where statement of the query.

Comment: Is this partitioned table ?

Comment: By `After running this code`, do you mean that you have run the exact SQL statement shown and nothing else?  That won't rebuild indexes, it will just generate the commands that you would use to rebuild indexes.

Comment: @DaveCosta
thanks for the suggesstion. I have managed to do it via for-loop. ` BEGIN FOR I IN ( SELECT OWNER, INDEX_NAME FROM all_indexes WHERE table_name = UPPER('JR_SETTING_D') ) LOOP BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || I.OWNER ||'.'|| I.INDEX_NAME || ' REBUILD' ; END; END LOOP; END; `

Answer (score 1):

If index (or its partition) is in unusable state and rebuild doesn't help, I'd suggest you to **drop** the index, insert data (will be *faster* as Oracle won't have to maintain the index during insert) and - once you're done - create the index again.

Comment: thanks for the suggesstion. I have managed to do it via for-loop. 
` BEGIN  
    FOR I IN  
      (  
             SELECT OWNER, INDEX_NAME FROM all_indexes WHERE table_name = UPPER('JR_SETTING_D')  
    )   
    LOOP  
        BEGIN  
              EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX ' || I.OWNER ||'.'|| I.INDEX_NAME || ' REBUILD' ;  
        END;  
    END LOOP;  
END;  `

Comment: You're welcome. Also, thank you for letting us know the way you managed to do it.